# Linkedin API to get public data

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to use the Linkedin API to get details of jobs posted by any company. This data seems to be public, so do I need to integrate Oauth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LinkedIn API isn't designed for developers to grab information and present it to people who haven't authenticated (public display).  Making calls as a single authenticated user to store it or present it elsewhere is against the Terms of Use for the API.  Additionally, you can't store the data you get - it's just designed to present to the authenticated user.

If you want to use the API to present this information, your users need to authenticate with LinkedIn and then you can make the call on their behalf.  This is probably easiest to do using the Javascript framework.

Comment: If a company official authenticates his linkedin account, then can I pull out this information and store in my DB?

Comment: @akshay3004 IANAL but I don't believe so - you _may_ however, be able to pull the info and present it to a user for editing/modification - and then save the user-edited info to your db - but that is nothing more than a guess and you'll need to examine the T&Cs closely

Comment: so why did they do this? public api could be much more useful for developing purposes imo

Answer (score 4):

The data is not quite public. You need an API key and you need oAuth to make API calls. Probably you dont need it if you just want the public profiles. Read the docs (RTFM).

http://developer.linkedin.com/rest

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/job-search-api

Comment: Ok...I have got an API key...but my question is whom should i authenticate?

Comment: you auth yourself with the key as a registered client for the API system which validates your request and it will send you back the data.