# Get linkedin public status updates

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to get latest 3 public activities of our company from linkedin (ex: http://www.linkedin.com/company/4043/activity) and present it on our website but unfortunately I dont see a clear explanation to do so in the API documentations. I registered an API Key but I am confused if I need to do OAuth if so against what and then what API to call to get publicly available info? 
Is OAuth really needed for something that is available? 
Can I store an OAuth token for an internal user and keep fetching data on that? I would really do not want to authenticated the site visitors with oauth to get free linkedin content.

This question is on the lines of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113699/linkedin-api-to-get-public-data), but I still wanted to ask and see if I could get a better response/answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the company updates from the LinkedIn API, you will need to reference the following document:

https://developer.linkedin.com/reading-company-updates

The API is currently in preview mode, but the above document addresses your question re: OAuth as well as shows the specific calls as well as sample output. If you have any questions after reviewing the docs, please feel free to visit our developer forums at:

https://developer.linkedin.com/forums/rest

And one of someone from our team would be more than happy to help you further.

Enjoy!

-Jeremy