# Get profile data from linkedin

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, api, linkedin-api

I just want to get profile data from linkedIn. I have searched a lot on google but did not find any end point which can return linked in data. Can i get public profile data by just passing a profile id of a user or company. Please provide suggestions to accomplish this task. Thanx in advance !

Comment: did you see this link? : http://developer.linkedin.com/apis

Comment: also this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113699/linkedin-api-to-get-public-data   according to this link,you can not get information of profile data

Comment: go to this url http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=120124037  not getting data. does it need authentication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out Spring.NET Social extension for LinkedIn :

http://www.springframework.net/social-linkedin/

Answer (score 0):

Although not a direct answer but have you checked the linkedin api documentation? https://developer.linkedin.com/apis provides some information on collecting some of the data from linkedin users.

Answer (score 0):

You can get through this [Profile API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api) which returns a member's LinkedIn profile.

The [LinkedIn Developer Toolkit](http://linkedintoolkit.codeplex.com/) is a open source library build in C# for using the LinkedIn® API in your .Net web applications.

Comment: go to this url... it should return data as per profile api but it is giving some error http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=120124037

Comment: That page from codeplex is gone. However here is a link from github. https://github.com/deeja/LinkedInDeveloperToolkit

Answer (score 0):

IDs used in the linkedin API are different from the IDs used on the linkedin website. In addition, each set of IDs is different to every linkedin application. This measure is there in order to prevent spammers from grabbing linkedin data.

What you would do is conduct a specific profile API search, or company API search, in order to get the ID you want, and then make a profile API call, or a company API call, in order to retrieve the details you need.